# Unable to update edmx with Mysql client

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-6, mysql-connector

While I am trying to update the edmx I am getting the following error, I am using visual studio 2017.

[image]

I have the following properties in my `app.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.12.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ProtocolNowDataModel.csdl|res://*/ProtocolNowDataModel.ssdl|res://*/ProtocolNowDataModel.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=latesttest;port=3306;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What I had also done was reinstall the MySQL for Visual Studio 1.2.8, then completely remove and install MySQL Connector 6.9.12.

[image]

I have already installed the following *.dll:

```
EntityFramework
MySql.Data.dll
MySql.Data.Entity.EF6.dll
```

[image]

Comment: There is no password in the connection string. Not only because you removed it in the question's code.

Comment: I don't have any password in the server as well